# Excel Validation depending on column value

Tags: excel, vba

My problem is the following. I'm working on an excel database and I have a table like the following one

Columna_A|Column_B

value 1........|..a

value 2........|..a

value 3........|..a

value 4........|..b

value 5........|..b

And I want to add a validation list that shows values depending on other field value that can be "a" or "b". I know that you can do this separating the lists and using the "=Indirect()" fórmula, but I need the lists to be on the same table.

Comment: So correct my understanding. if the user types value 5 in a cell, you want to show "b" in the cell next to it?

Comment: i wan't the opposite of that, you must type "a" or "b" on the field, and if you type "a" the dropdown validation list displays only "value_1, value_2" and "value_3", and if you type "b" now the values on the dropdown validation list must be "value_4" and "value_5"

Comment: I see... See this http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/29/excel-data-validationcreate-dynamic-dependent-lists-vba/ :)

Comment: Is it something like this?: http://www.bumpclub.ee/~jyri_r/Excel/Dynamic_dropdown_lists.xls

Comment: Siddarth: Your solution is what I was looking for, but I can't make it work on my PC, I have the latin american student version from office 2011 (MAC)

Juri: thanks, but it isn't what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I did.

First I selected the cell range I planned to do data validation on.

In my case it was B1:B7.

Then I selected the "Allow:" under Validation criteria and Selected "List".

I then placed this formula in the "Source:"

```
    =IF(A1="a",$C$1:$C$3,$D$1:$D$3)
```

If you don't anchor (don't use $ symbols) for A1 it will adjust the formula to be continuous on all the cells from B1:B7.  For example, Data validation will change the formula for B3 to:
        =IF(A3="a",$C$1:$C$3,$D$1:$D$3)

Observe:

[image: For value 'a']

[image: For another value besides 'a']

I can upload this workbook somewhere if you'd like.

Comment: i'm looking for a way of doing that without having to separate the data bases. thanks anyway